# Extension update ( Based on another field)

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Extension Update-

I have two data extensions, Data Extension "A" and Data Extension "B". I want to add the data of Data Extension "B" to Data Extension "A".

Problem - I want to update the Data Extension "A" prov Field to QC if lang = "fr"

EXAMPLE -

```
IF LANG = 'EN-QC' THEN PROV = 'QC'
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll have to use a query activity and a [Case statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) in the SQL query. For example:

```
CASE WHEN Lang = ‘EN-QC’ THEN ‘QC’ 
END AS Prov
```

Comment: I think you @ mentioned the wrong person

Comment: Oh Sorry, Thank you @jackson Chen :)